# Erro no excel vba, uzando o .offset, para pesquisa de produtos em uma planilha

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Olá, estou tentando aprender excell vba para ajudar meu pai na empresa dele, utilizo a versão do excel 2016, no código que montei seguindo o curso, era pra hora que eu digitar o código do produto, ele mostra o fabricante, número e nome da peça, mas ele só reconhece a primeira linha da planilha onde está os produtos, espero que me ajudem, agradeço desde já! Código:

```
Private Sub Btnconsultar_Click()

 Dim EmpFound As Range
 
 With Range("Códigos_valv")
 
 Set EmpFound = .Find(Me.Txt_cod.Value)
 
 If EmpFound Is Nothing Then
    
    MsgBox "Válvula não encontrada", vbCritical, "Consultar válvula"
    
    Me.Txt_cod.Value = ""
    
    Else
    
    With Range(EmpFound.Address)
    
    Me.Txt_numero = .Offset(0, 1)
    Me.Txt_nomeval = .Offset(0, 2)
    Me.Txt_fabri = .Offset(0, 3)
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.Ifoto1.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\RRG Type\para converter\Imagens para cadastro\Imagens válvulas\" & EmpFound & ".jpg")
    
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    End With
 End If
End With

 Set EmpFound = Nothing   
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Por favor, poderia fornecer mais detalhes do motivo de uso do VBA nesse caso? Pergunto, pois como se trata da busca de um produto por um código único, o uso do =PROCV(VLOOKUP) na planilha traria todas as informações de que você precisa (se preciso, mostro aqui como ela poderia ser aplicada).

Além disso, lendo o código, parece haver a necessidade de carregar uma imagem também. Essa imagem também precisaria ser carregada via vba por algum motivo específico?

Assim que você puder responder aqui, eu poderei dar uma solução mais concreta para o seu problema.

At.te,